# Unable Force Download File in Django HttpResponse (HTML/ PDF)

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to output HTML or PDF files for download. I have written few lines of code to generate html & PDF file from a template and download it.

1. However, my code is working for **Chrome browser only**. When I try to download it from other browser (e.g. DuckDuckGo) I am getting my current page (i.e. roll.html) downloaded instead of the file (i.e. file rendered from html_output_template.html) which I want to export.

Here's the code I am trying: **views.py**

```
def generate_html(request, res):
    cdict = {'res':res, 'date':datetime.date.today()}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        inv_form = InvoiceInfoForm(data= request.POST)
        if inv_form.is_valid():
            inv_data  = inv_form.cleaned_data
            cdict = {'res':res, 'inv_data':inv_data, 'date':datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d %h %Y")}
    template = get_template('app_name/html_output_template.html')
    html  = template.render(cdict)
    response = HttpResponse(html, content_type='application/force-download')
    filename = "Inv_%s.html" %(datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d_%h_%y_%H_%M_%S"))
    content = "attachment; filename= %s" %(filename)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = content
    return response


def MyView(request):
    """Some 
    Calculations 
    Here"""

    if 'download_pdf' in request.POST:
        if inv_form.is_valid():
            return generate_pdf(request, res)
    elif 'download_html' in request.POST:
        if inv_form.is_valid():
            return generate_html(request, res)

    return render(request,'app_name/roll.html',context=cdict)
```

Sample of html template: **html_output_template.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!-- Few Lines here -->
       <tr>
          <td style="text-align:left">1</td>
          <td style="text-align:left">{{inv_data.description}}</td>
          <td style="text-align:right">{{res.rate_per_gram}} {{res.rate_kilo_gram}}</td>
          <td style="text-align:right">{{res.wgt_of_goods}}</td>
          <td style="text-align:right">{{res.total_amount}}</td>
        </tr>
```

I feel there is some problem with my `HttpResponse` which is getting auto corrected in Chrome and not in other browsers. I am unable to resolve this please help

Comment: Weird error!!! Have you tested on other browsers, such as IE, FireFox?

Comment: I forgot to mention few things:
I am testing it on **Android Mobile's** browser DuckDuckGo (not working), Chrome(Working)
I have tested it on Computer for Chrome,  IE and Edge it is working there. :(

Comment: No idea! Maybe to do with security system of DuckDuckgo preventing any download, though I am not entirely sure.